# OpenLayers How do I change from OSM to TMS?

Tags: openlayers

I have created a simple html to test some map tiles i made. The trouble is that I made them useing TMS projection but I used an OSM example, so all my tiles are showing upside down verticly. I tried switching to TMS, but after few dozen of failed atempts it seems that I am missing something, can anyone please help fix the code?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="OpenStreetMap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var map, layer;

        //Initialise the 'map' object
        function init() {

            map = new OpenLayers.Map ("map", {
                controls:[
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({geodesic: true}),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink('permalink'),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),                    
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()],
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds( 0.0, -10000.0, 10000.0, 0.0),
                maxResolution: 64.000000,
                numZoomLevels: 7,
                units: 'm',
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            } );

            // Add Base map.
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Base Map", "tiles/base/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg", {numZoomLevels: 7, alpha: false, isBaseLayer: true});
            map.addLayer(layer);

            // Add Layers.
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Terrain", "tiles/terrain/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 7, alpha: false, isBaseLayer: false});
            map.addLayer(layer);
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Lables", "tiles/lables/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 7, alpha: false, isBaseLayer: false});
            map.addLayer(layer);

            var switcherControl = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
            map.addControl(switcherControl);
            switcherControl.maximizeControl();

            if( ! map.getCenter() ){
                var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(10, 10).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
                map.setCenter (lonLat, 5);
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
    <body onload="init();">
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Basicly all I need is one Base map layer(jpg) and few optional layers(png with transparency) all using TMS, 256x256, 7 zoom levels and located at 'tiles/layername/...'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but this may help:

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/UsingCustomTiles